# Applying JOLT Transform to JSON data

Tags: jolt

My input JSON is as below.

```json
{
  "identifier": "0134",
  "language": "EN",
  "questType": "JSQ",
  "questionHtml": "<div></div>"
}
```

And the expected output is

```json
{
  "0134":{
  "identifier": "0134",
  "language": "EN",
  "questType": "JSQ",
  "questionHtml": "<div></div>"
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this using JOLT transformation?

Answer (score 0):

This spec should work for you:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@(1,identifier).&"
    }
  }
]
```

See [`@` wildcard docs](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java#L300)

Tested with https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/